# "lookup-name" of JNDI entry in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jndi

I have few applications that use JNDI properties configured in its web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>application1/username</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>admin3</env-entry-value>
    <lookup-name>username</lookup-name>
</env-entry>
```

I cannot get the entry by lookup name, following code returns null:

```
String jndiValue = jndiValue = ((Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("username").toString();
```

It seems like Tomcat do not support this attribute, is it right?

Comment: Does tomcat implementation support something called `<lookup-name>` ?

Answer (score 1):

> application1/username

So the partial name is `application1/username`.

> String jndiValue = jndiValue = ((Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env")).lookup("username").toString();

So you are looking up the partial name `username`.

You can simplify it as well. You don't need the nested `Context`, or the two `Context` leaks, or the `toString()` part either:

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
String jndiValue = jndiValue = initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/application1/username");
initialContext.close();
```

Comment: I think you need to correct "partial name ..." line. it is application1/username.